# What does a hash token (#) do in an object macro expansion list?

Tags: c++

I've been trying to understand the description of macro expansion in the C++ preprocessor as described in an early draft of the C++14 standard.  (It's the version I could get for free, and I doubt the preprocessor has changed much since.)

The draft gives an example:

```
#define hash_hash # ## #
```

and shows that this expands as ##.   I've verified that g++ has this behavior. But I cannot find an explanation for it in the actual normative text of the standard, which explains that # before a parameter name in a function macro stringizes the corresponding argument (which I understand just fine) but says nothing about what it means in any other context.

I'm even more puzzled when I see that

```
#define pound #
```

expands as #, exactly as I would have initially expected.

Comment: The expansion of `# ## #` to `##` isn't about the stringize operation but rather due to the token-concatenation operator `##`. I think.

Comment: The example explains that the ## is not a concatenation operator when expanded, e.g.  ``` c hash_hash c ``` fully expands to ```c ## d```. Which puzzles me further.

Comment: The example shows you how to "escape" the two hash sequence in a macro. It takes the first and last hash and concatenated them using the middle double hash, which when used in another macro puts the double hash sequence on output. There is no other way how to write double hash in the middle of a macro without it concatenation the neighbouring tokens and disappearing.

Comment: Ah. Thanks, MadKarel. That makes it fairly clear. So concatenation of two hashes produces a single double hash token that is not a concatenation operator. I'll got back to the standard to understand better why this is the case.

Comment: @MadKarel - that sounds like an answer (a good answer, too) - you should write it as an Answer, rather than in the comments!

Answer (score 3):

The example shows you how to "escape" the two hash sequence in a macro. It takes the first and last hash and concatenates them using the middle double hash, which when used in another macro puts the double hash sequence on output. There is no other way how to write double hash in the middle of a macro without it concatenation the neighbouring tokens and disappearing.

This happens because C++ is designed to be compiled in one pass, so once the `# ## #` sequence is preprocessed by the preprocessor into `##`, it is never "preprocessed" again.

Comment: The preprocessor isn't _strictly_ single pass, since macro expansions are rescanned, which is a kind of limited local second pass.

Comment: But I think I understand now. The # ## # concatenates the two hashes into a single ##, which is not treated as a concatenation operator on rescanning because it is not part of a replacement list. The standard only talks about ## when one of the neighbor tokens is a parameter name; you have to infer from the example that it pastes whatever two tokens adjoin it in the replacement list even if neither is a parameter name.